# React Router history on browser's back button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, browser-history

I have a home component with a link which loads  a display component and in display component i have the same link which loads the display component again.

if user clicks the link many times in Display Component then there will be a lot of router history.i want that when a user clicks the browser back button it should load the home component not all the previous history.

when i use `history.replace("/");` in Display component with onClick event then it works only one time back.but again back is resulting the previous history of Display Component

**Routes.js**

```
import Home from "./Components/Home"
import Display from "./Components/Display"

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:city">
            <Display />
        </Route>        
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

**Home.js**

```
<Link to ={`/${city}`} onClick={()=>{dispatch(fetchWeather(city)); }}>Search</Link>
```

**Display.js**

```
<Link to ={`/${city}`} onClick={()=>{dispatch(fetchWeather(city)); }}>Search</Link>
```

Comment: Did you try to tell the link component to replace? `<Link replace to={} />`. Alternatively you could define a function to handle this for you, not let the links default behavior of redirecting go through and instead use react routers `history` to replace the state inside `Display`. This way every city click will update the current history state with the new target... and a back button press would go to home. If this works for you i'd be happy to write it up as an answer :)

Comment: Agreed, the `Link` in `Display` should be a redirect to self (`REPLACE`), not a navigation (`PUSH`). This will just replace the current entry instead of pushing on  page after page. When a back navigation is done (`POP`) user go back to the home page.

Comment: @JohnRuddell can you write the answer,  am keen to see how this should be implemented :-)

Comment: @Shyam It's literally ***just*** adding a `replace` prop to the `Link`. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/replace-bool

Comment: @DrewReese Oh okay , haven't encountered this use case before . Its good to know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of react router you are using you can just add the `replace` prop on your `Link` component in the `Display.js` file to not push new states on the history stack and instead update the current one.

```
<Link replace to ={`/${city}`} onClick={()=>{dispatch(fetchWeather(city)); }}>Search</Link>
```

If you're on an older version where this isn't supported what you can do is have a click handler do this for you

```
// Display.js file

function Display(props) {
  // whatever code you have for this file
  const handleViewCity = useCallback((event, city) => {
    // prevent the default redirect from happening, were going to manage that ourselves
    event.preventDefault()

    dispatch(fetchWeather(city))
    props.history.replace(`/${city}`)

  }, [props.history, fetchWeather])

  return (
    // your jsx
    // keep the href so you get browser builtin functionality like right click "open in new window"
    <a href={`/${city}`} onClick={(e) => handleViewCity(e, city)}>Search</Link>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Display)
```

---

To visualize what would be happening here think of history as a stack of locations. (this is a simple example - pseudo code)

```
history.push('/city1') // ['/home', '/city1']
history.push('/city2') // ['/home', '/city1', '/city2']
history.push('/city3') // ['/home', '/city1', '/city2', '/city3']
```

Pressing the browser back button fires a window `popstate` event. Pop being the keyword there. When the browser back button is pressed your history then looks like this `['/home', '/city1', '/city2']`, which is why you were seeing different cities from the history.

Instead you want to use replace to achieve the desired effect

```
history.replace('/city1') // ['/home', '/city1']
history.replace('/city2') // ['/home', '/city2']
history.replace('/city3') // ['/home', '/city3']
```